# Configure single Tomcat webapp to ignore Tomcat/libs log4j jar due to conflict

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, log4j2, external-dependencies

I have a Java webapp using Spring Boot which runs fine, and I have been using SLF4J (with log4j2).
This all works - and logs out to the correct files - in my local Tomcat instance which has no conflicting Jars in the classpath.

However when deploying into the production environment, there seems to be an existing log4j jar file in the Tomcat/lib directory (which beats my own log4j2 jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory). I get some errors on startup which don't seem to relate to my own config since the number of loggers/properties doesn't match up.

I have only limited control over the production Tomcat environment, so ideally I'd like to be able to restrict which libraries are included in the classpath for *my webapp alone* without changing configuration for others deployed in the same Tomcat instance.

My question therefore, is:
Is it possible to exclude the provided log4j jar from my app only, and instead use my supplied log4j2 jar?

Thanks in advance!

**Errors on startup**

```
2016-03-07 15:34:29,346 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Error processing element appender ([configuration: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2016-03-07 15:34:29,347 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Error processing element appender ([configuration: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2016-03-07 15:34:29,347 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Error processing element appender ([configuration: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2016-03-07 15:34:29,348 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Error processing element appender ([configuration: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2016-03-07 15:34:29,349 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR property contains an invalid element or attribute "value"
2016-03-07 15:34:29,349 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "property" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property is ignored.
2016-03-07 15:34:29,350 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "logger" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored.
2016-03-07 15:34:29,350 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "logger" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored.
2016-03-07 15:34:29,351 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "logger" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored.
2016-03-07 15:34:29,352 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "logger" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored.
2016-03-07 15:34:29,352 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "logger" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored.
2016-03-07 15:34:29,353 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "logger" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored.
2016-03-07 15:34:29,353 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "root" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored.
2016-03-07 15:34:29,354 localhost-startStop-10 ERROR Unknown object "logger" of type org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig is ignored.
```

**log4j2.xml config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration name="PSPCC" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATH">logs</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%clr{%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}{faint} %clr{%5p} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{--}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n%wEx</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${LOG_PATH}/pspcc.log"
                     filePattern="${LOG_PATH}/pspcc-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log" append="true">
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn" />
        <Logger name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" level="warn" />
        <Logger name="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool" level="warn" />
        <Logger name="org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory" level="error" />
        <Logger name="org.springframework.security.saml" level="debug" />
        <Logger name="org.springframework.security" level="info" />

        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```